# How to convert a string variable to a string array

Tags: android, arrays, string, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am making a request from my app to a server which is returning an array. I want to put that array into a listView but the the whole array is treated as a single listItem.

As the response is recieved in a string variable i want to convert it to a string array?

any help is appretiated.. Thanks

Comment: Can you post that array format? If its string use split method to split the String and prepare an array

Comment: Do String manipulation on the received string variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace **arr** with your String Array variable name:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s : arr) {
        builder.append(s);
    }
    String str = builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly string response data split by space[Available special character] or assign string array.

```
String yourdata = "A B C D E F G H";
String[] yourtDataArr = yourdata.split(" ");

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

for(i =0;i<yourtDataArr.length;i++){

   list.add(yourtDataArr[i]);
}
```

Then use your list on ListView. You can see following example.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm

http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php